# How to catch exceptions with Qt platform independently?

Tags: c++, qt, exception, cross-platform

I'm using boost::date_time in my project. When date is not valid it thorws std::out_of_range C++ exception. In Qt's gui application on windows platform it becomes SEH exception, so it doesn't catched with try|catch paradigm and programm dies. How can I catch the exception platform independently?

```
try{
    std::string ts("9999-99-99 99:99:99.999");
    ptime t(time_from_string(ts))
}
catch(...)
{
    // doesn't work on windows
}
```

---

**EDITED:**
If somebody didn't understand, I wrote another example:

**Qt pro file:**

```
TEMPLATE = app
DESTDIR  = bin
VERSION  = 1.0.0
CONFIG  += debug_and_release build_all
TARGET = QExceptExample
SOURCES += exceptexample.cpp \
           main.cpp
HEADERS += exceptexample.h
```

**exceptexample.h**

```
#ifndef __EXCEPTEXAMPLE_H__
#define __EXCEPTEXAMPLE_H__

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui/QMessageBox>
#include <QtGui/QPushButton>
#include <stdexcept>

class PushButton;
class QMessageBox;

class ExceptExample : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    ExceptExample();
    ~ExceptExample();
  public slots:
    void throwExcept();
  private:
    QPushButton * throwBtn;
};

#endif
```

**exceptexample.cpp**

```
#include "exceptexample.h"

ExceptExample::ExceptExample()
{
  throwBtn = new QPushButton(this);
  connect(throwBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(throwExcept()));
}

ExceptExample::~ExceptExample()
{
}

void ExceptExample::throwExcept()
{
  QMessageBox::information(this, "info", "We are in throwExcept()", 
                           QMessageBox::Ok);
  try{
    throw std::out_of_range("ExceptExample");
  }
  catch(...){
    QMessageBox::information(this, "hidden", "Windows users can't see "
                             "this message", QMessageBox::Ok);
  }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "exceptexample.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  ExceptExample e;
  e.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: What does it have to do with Qt? You don't use any Qt classes in your code.

Comment: The error is actual in Qt. This code works fine except Qt-windows-gui, because, I think, it re-throws std C++ exceptions as SEH, so the application falls (catch doesn't work).

Comment: I don't see how this has to do with Qt either. You have local non-Qt code that throws an exception, and a try catch-block around that. Also catch(...) should catch everything. The only issue with Qt would be if the exception ends up in the Qt event loop, which isn't the case here. And what's SEH?

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld catch(...) shouldn't catch SEH. See Structured Exception Handling.

Comment: Is your Qt library compiled with C++ exception support enabled?  Sometimes they're not, which causes problems.

Comment: @aschelper I used default windows binaries. How can I find out how it was configured?

Comment: Can't you wrap the main in a try/catch?

Comment: @Appu unfortunately can't. Trying to instantiate ptime is date validation.

Comment: @aschelper I reconfigured Qt with -exceptions option. It fixed situation. If you'll  post the answer I'll mark it as right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding answer from the comments:

[aschelper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640/aschepler) wrote:

> Is your Qt library compiled with C++
>   exception support enabled? Sometimes
>   they're not, which causes problems.

[hoxnox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287612/hoxnox) (OP) answered:

> @aschelper I reconfigured Qt with
>   -exceptions option. It fixed situation. If you'll post the answer
>   I'll mark it as right.