# How to enable exceptions handling in qt

Tags: c++, qt, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my code compile with -fno-exceptions in Qt Creator when I try to use exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802992/why-does-my-code-compile-with-fno-exceptions-in-qt-creator-when-i-try-to-use-ex)

Even though I have in my .pro file line:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++0x -pedantic -fexceptions
```

I'm still getting error during compilation:

```
 error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
```

Any ideas why, and how can I enable exceptions handling in qt?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802992/why-does-my-code-compile-with-fno-exceptions-in-qt-creator-when-i-try-to-use-ex

or 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449095/how-to-catch-exceptions-with-qt-platform-independently

check those threads :)

Comment: @cojack thanks, I see one of my threads there ;). Unfortunately, this time adding Config += -fexceptions doesn't seem to work. I'm still getting the error.

Comment: are you sure yours qt environment is compiled with -exceptions option?

Comment: @cojack I've build my qt according to http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MinGW, so I'm not sure now. There isn't option -fno-exceptions specified anywhere but I cannot be sure. What is your opinion?

Comment: I can only guess that your qt sdk is builded without -exceptions flags, no other idea, sorry :<

Comment: @cojack isn't that pathetic? in 2012 not using exceptions? I do like qt, but some of their ideas are just so...

Comment: not at all, check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548951/why-doesnt-qt-use-exception-handling will explain this part :)

Comment: @cojack well, it simply states for historical reason. To me this is pathetic and backward thinking. We don't live in caves although for historical reasons we bloody well should.

Comment: @smallB Qt doesn't throw exceptions (in the 'older' modules), but that doesn't mean _you_ can't.  The Qt packages I got from my distro have no problem with me throwing exceptions so it must be the way it is being compiled.  Is there any reason why you are building Qt yourself instead of just downloading the Windows libraries?

Comment: @cmannett85 yes, the reason is that I need to build them myself in order to have this build compatible with my compiler, otherwise I'm getting unwind errors. Anyway, I know that I can throw exceptions, the pathetic side of qt approach is that by default they don't enable it. In 2012!

Comment: People have different feelings about exceptions, especially in C++. Personally, I use them in C# and Java, but I try to avoid them in C++/Qt. There's a good blog post about the pros and cons here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38449/C-Exceptions-Pros-and-Cons